# What does upper/lower bits mean?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, inode

I'm learning a bit about Ext4 file system [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/dynamic.html#dynamic-structures). In the first table on this link they are describing fields of the inode. Each field entry has an:

- offset
- size
- name
- description

In the description field the document states some of these values are Lower or Higher bits. What does lower/highter bits mean, and what is the explanation behind use of the concept in this ext4 file system example?

Comment: I think this can help you: [Least significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit), [Most significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_bit).

Comment: did you read the comment on that LSB/MSB article at the top. It say s the document has many inaccuracies.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I've updated the question based on your comment.

Comment: Yes, if you're allowed to keep the change, you should pay special attention to the "lower dolars". With `$125` you may not get anything, and with `$129` you may get too little. Make up something like `$127.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take one example, using the [doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/dynamic.html#dynamic-structures) that you link to in your question for reference: the `i_uid` field has size `__le16` and is described as `Lower 16-bits of Owner UID`. If the system which created this filesystem allows 16-bit user IDs only, then all of the user ID can fit into the `i_uid` field: `__le16` does indeed stand for "little-endian 16 bits". in your analogy, if you can only have two-digit numbers and the cost is $29, you are all set because it fits.

If it uses 32-bit user IDs (I'm pretty sure no system uses bigger ones), then the 32-bit user ID will not fit into a field of size `__le16`, so the 32 bits are split into two 16-bit quantities. If we number the bits from 0 for the least significant bit to 31 for the most significant bit (which is just our convention here for making things unambiguous) then bits 0-15 (the "low-order" bits) are put into the `i_uid` field, but bits 16-31 (the "high-order" bits) don't fit and will have to go somewhere else: on Linux which uses 32-bit user IDs, they end up in the subfield `l_i_uid_high` of the `osd2` field of the inode. In your analogy, if the cost is $129 but you have two-digit boxes, then `29` would fit into the low-order two-digit box, and `01` would go into the high-order two-digit box.

A couple of additional points: note that all the fields are "little-endian" - if the field consists of more than one byte (e.g. `__le16` consists of two bytes), then the least-significant byte comes first and the most-significant byte comes second in the order, but they are adjacent. That is *regardless* of the endianness of the CPU of the system: that way, the way that the filesystem is laid out on disk is independent of the CPU that laid it out; you could read this filesystem on a different system with the opposite endianness if you wanted (with the caveat that the versions of ext4 running on the two systems should be compatible).

Note also that the low-order 16 bits (= 2 bytes) of the user ID and the high-order 16 bits of the user ID are stored at two places on the disk that are *not* adjacent: the first one is at offset 0x2 from the the beginning of the inode, but the second one is at offset 0x74 + 0x4 from the beginning of the inode: 0x74 is where the 12-byte `i_osd2` field starts and 0x4 is the offset of `l_i_uid_high` from the beginning of the `i_osd2` field. That probably came about because at some point, "all the world was 16-bit user ids", so early filesystems only reserved the first field for the user id. When the necessity to use 32-bit user ids arose, the second 16 bits could not be placed adjacently, since other fields were already there (in this case the `i_size` field, which was originally limited to 32-bits, but that too proved too small, so eventually an `i_size_field` was added to get another 32 bits of size - see offset 0x6C in the inode), so it was placed at (probably) the first location in the inode which was unused and available for use.

A lot of this complexity was necessitated by backward-compatibility considerations (ext4 wanted to be able to read ext3 filesystems without the user having to do anything special) and by the desire to accommodate future expansion. With 20/20 hindsight, all of the scattered pieces could be put together and you would see e.g. an `i_uid` of type `__le32` instead of having to split it into two pieces. But that's the kind of thing you have to do to move forward without abandoning everything that has gone before.

Comment: This is a good answer, but maybe somewhat over complicated. I think the last two paragraphs contain the answer to OP's question. Maybe summarize those at the top and go into more detail below?

Comment: You mean the "couple of additional points"? If so, I disagree: they may explain why the layout is as it is, but they do *not* answer the question. It's the first two paragraphs that do that.